# Set two different lock setting on different triggers

Tags: lock-screens, password

I am using Android L on Lenovo phone. Mostly I don't hand out my phone to anybody or keep it unattended. So, I prefer not to bother myself with a lock (password or pin) and just keep swipe lock screen. But while many a times when I have to keep my phone away from my attention, I want to put lock password over it.
For this I have to go to the settings and change it and change it back when I am done.
Is there a way to keep two different lock screen setting(say swipe and pass) on two different triggers (say power button and option on long press power button menu)?

Comment: Raw idea: Smart lock. If you have e.g. any Bluetooth device, you can tell your Android device it's "safe" as long as it can see it (so: no lock), but "not safe" otherwise (lock). To have your device locked, you'd simply have to shutdown or disconnect the BT device. Works natively with Android 5+ – and for earlier versions, there might be fitting apps. Would that match your needs?

Comment: @Izzy It does help. I ended up using a combination of location and Bluetooth based smart lock. There was a face lock as well, which could work as well, whose accuracy I didn't yet checked.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, trevis! Mind to make your solution an answer (and "accept" that 2 days later)? That way it becomes clear also from lists that your issue was solved, which again might help others in a similar situation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Although I believe, you should get the credit. I would accept your answer, as my approach was nothing but driven by your response. Sorry for not responding in time, wasn't available at all.

Comment: As you wish – so I expanded my comment to a full-fledged answer, including hints for "lower Android versions" not yet equipped with the "smart lock" feature natively. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Android's *Smart Lock* feature for this, see e.g.:

- [Use Smart Lock in Android 5.0 and Never Unlock Your Phone at Home Again](http://www.howtogeek.com/202881/use-smart-locks-in-android-5.0-and-never-unlock-your-phone-at-home-again/)
- [How to use Trusted Devices in Android](http://www.androidcentral.com/how-use-trusted-devices-android-50-lollipop)

If you have e.g. any Bluetooth device, you can tell your Android device it's "safe" as long as it can see it (so: no lock), but "not safe" otherwise (device gets locked). To have your device locked, you'd simply have to shutdown or disconnect the BT device (or have it out-of-reach; for Bluetooth-devices usually being away 10m is enough – even less with walls in between).

*Smart Lock* works natively with Android 5+ – and for earlier versions, there are fitting apps (e.g. [Zwype Lock Screen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zighra.zwypelockss), [SkipLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.benhirashima.skiplock), or using one of the more generic [automation](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/automation/info) solutions to build your own: I e.g. use [tasker](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info) with the *Secure Settings* plugin for this).